# Why $e^{x^2+\alpha x}\sim e^{x^2}$ as $x\rightarrow +\infty$ iff $\alpha=0$?

Tags: calculus, limits

Since  $x^2$ is asymptotically faster than $\alpha x$, then why $e^{x^2+\alpha x}\sim e^{x^2}$ as $x\rightarrow +\infty$ iff $\alpha=0$?

Comment: $e^{x^2+\alpha x}/e^{x^2}=e^{\alpha x}$

Comment: What is the definition of the $\sim$ relation?

Comment: It means that if you divide the left by the right, then the limit is $1$.

Comment: **Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange!** A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  For equations, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 2):

We can see that 
$$\frac{e^{x^2+\alpha x}}{e^{x^2}}=e^{\alpha x}$$
and 
$$ \lim_{x\to\infty} e^{\alpha x}=
\begin{cases}
\infty&\alpha>0\\
1&\alpha=0\\
0&\alpha<0.
\end{cases}$$
So, $e^{x^2+\alpha x}\sim e^{x^2}$ if and only if $\alpha=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Clearly, $$\frac{e^{x^2+\alpha x}}{e^{x^2}}=e^{\alpha x}.$$ If $\alpha=0,$ then this is identically $1$. On the other hand, if $$\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} e^{\alpha x}=1,$$ then hopefully it's obvious that you need $\alpha=0.$ Indeed, if $\alpha>0,$ then this limit is infinity, and if $\alpha<0,$ then the limit is $0$.

Comment: Sorry, accidentally I put -1 when I was trying to put +1.